# Is there any better way to restart java threads?

Tags: java, multithreading

1)Is there any better way to restart threads?

2)Is it ok to call `Thread.isAlive()` so often?

3)If not, can you advise the other solution for this?

```
class AllActions{
    LinkedBlockingQueue<String> action1list = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    LinkedBlockingQueue<String> action2list = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    LinkedBlockingQueue<String> action3list = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    doActions(List<String> actions){

    action1list.addAll(actions);

    Thread action1Thread = new Thread(this::doAction1);
    Thread action2Thread = new Thread(this::doAction2);
    Thread action3Thread = new Thread(this::doAction3);

        do{
            if (!action1list.isEmpty() && !action1Thread.isAlive()) {
                    action1Thread = new Thread(this::doAction1);
                    action1Thread.start();
                }

            if (!action2list.isEmpty() && !action2Thread.isAlive()) {
                    action2Thread = new Thread(this::doAction2);
                    action2Thread.start();
                }
            if (!action3list.isEmpty() && !action3Thread.isAlive()) {
                    action3Thread = new Thread(this::doAction3);
                    action3Thread.start();
                }
        }while( /*All lists have something and any thread is alive */)
}

    doAction1(){
        action1list.take()
        /* some things */
        action2list.put()
    }
    /* Other actions */
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't "restart" a Java thread.  Once it has terminated, it cannot be restarted.

But that's not what you are doing.  What you are actually doing is repeatedly creating and starting (not restarting) *new* threads.  That is inefficient because thread start and exit are rather expensive.  In addition, the "main" thread is polling the other threads to see if they are still alive, which is another inefficiency.

There *definitely* is a better way.

Look at the `ExecutorService` API.  It allows you to submit an indefinite number of "tasks" to a work queue and have a pool of threads process them.  The API takes care of starting the worker threads, passing them tasks, and restarting if they crash.  Executor services can be instantiated with fixed size pools, pools that shrink and grow, infinite of bounded work queues, and so on.

For more information; start with the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and the [Oracle tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) on this topic.

Comment: As I understand it will be like this: 

`while(lists have something ) {

executor.submit(thread) 

}` ? Am I write?

Comment: Nope.  Don't submit threads.  Submit tasks; e.g. `Runnable` or `Callable` instances.  It is all explained in the tutorials.